# Scroll IFrame to Top does not work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

While clicking on an element, users can open a modal window DIV overlaying the full window — its content is about 100px height, the rest of the window will be blacked out. This overlay-div has to be absolutely positioned with top:3rem due to other reasons.

In accessibility-matters, while opening the modal window I set the focus to the overlay-div, therefore ScreenReaders like VoiceOver know where to continue — and Browsers jump their viewport to top e.g. to the overlay-window.

This works perfectly in all browsers across desktop and mobile and with all screenreaders etc. while using the site on its own. All browser-viewports jump up to the top to show the overlay-div in its full glory.

BUT if I include the website via IFrame into another, this «viewport-jumping to the overlay-div» does work in all browsers EXCEPT Google Chrome on Desktop and Android. :-/ interestingly scrollTop() does not work neither. Chrome just stays where it was and I have to scroll up manually to see the overlay-div.

Any Idea how to force the iframe (or the parent window) to scroll to top (or a defined px-from-top)?

Comment: Can you share your code or send us link to debug the issue

Comment: Unless it's a link to jsfiddle or an alternative, show the code, so future readers can see it as well.

Comment: @AliMehdi: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2481934/site/dataTiles2/index.html

Comment: @Psioniax: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2481934/site/dataTiles2/index.html

Comment: … if you click once or twice on «Mehr laden» and then scroll down and Click on the «Andorra», the viewport jumps up … if you include the page within an IFrame, it does not with Chrome.

Comment: Which library are you using for tiles?

Comment: Just tested, it doesn't in Chrome indeed.

Comment: @AliMehdi: I'm using jQuery for the JS — but no other library, plugin what-so-ever

Comment: Issue is consistent in both the browsers..

Comment: Is it fixed? I am unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1529630). You must include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it with a manually scrollTo onClick with JS.

Seams to be a Bug in Chrome — I reported it already.

Comment: For reference, it would be better if you linked the bug report in the answer.

Comment: @Oriol: I would, if I could — but Google did not sent me a Link or forwarded me to a page where I could see the report … just a thank-you-note :-/

Comment: How did you report the bug? Usually it's done by creating a "New issue" on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/, then the link would be like https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=<ID>

Comment: @Oriol: I googled and found this: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315 … and thats how I did it.

Comment: Now only Google might see your report, and I wouldn't trust that. Chromium is an open source project, posting on bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues would allow anyone to see (and maybe fix) it.